# Change a Property for All Objects in an NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c, properties, nsstring, nsmutablearray

I have an `NSMutableArray` with 9 objects. Those objects have many properties, like `questionName`, `questionWhatRow`, etc.

I want to be able to change one of those properties for **All** of the objects in the `NSMutableArray`.

Here is my NSMutableArray Class.

```
-(id) init
{
    self = [super init];
    
    if (self)
    {
        self.questionsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        
        Question *newQuestion = [[Question alloc] init];
        newQuestion.questionName = @"What is the name of the girl who has to fetch water for her family every day?";
        newQuestion.questionRowName = @"Question 1";
        newQuestion.questionAnswer = @"Nya";
        newQuestion.questionHint = @"Maybe if you read the book you would know";
        newQuestion.questionWhatRow = @"Nya";
        newQuestion.questionCompleteOrNot = @"No";
        newQuestion.pointForQuestion = 1;
        [self.questionsArray addObject:newQuestion];
        
        newQuestion = [[Question alloc] init];
        newQuestion.questionName = @"What is Nya's sister's name?";
        newQuestion.questionRowName = @"Question 2";
        newQuestion.questionAnswer = @"Akeer";
        newQuestion.questionHint = @"Maybe if you read the book you would know";
        newQuestion.questionWhatRow = @"Nya";
        newQuestion.questionCompleteOrNot = @"No";
        newQuestion.pointForQuestion = 1;
        [self.questionsArray addObject:newQuestion];
        
        newQuestion = [[Question alloc] init];
        newQuestion.questionName = @"What people is Nya's mother scared of when her father and sons go hunting?";
        newQuestion.questionRowName = @"Question 3";
        newQuestion.questionAnswer = @"Dinka";
        newQuestion.questionHint = @"Maybe if you read the book you would know";
        newQuestion.questionWhatRow = @"Nya";
        newQuestion.questionCompleteOrNot = @"No";
        newQuestion.pointForQuestion = 1;
        [self.questionsArray addObject:newQuestion];
        
        newQuestion = [[Question alloc] init];
        newQuestion.questionName = @"What is Salva scared of when he is in the Akobo desert?";
        newQuestion.questionRowName = @"Question 4";
        newQuestion.questionAnswer = @"Lions";
        newQuestion.questionHint = @"He is scared of an animal because it ate his friend Marial";

        
        newQuestion = nil;
                
    }
    
    return self;
}

-(NSUInteger)count
{
    return questionsArray.count;
}


- (Question *)questionAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index
{
    return [questionsArray objectAtIndex:index];
}
```

Now, I have another class called `ScoreViewController`, and I want to be able to change the property, `questionCompleteOrNot` of the `NSMutableArray` `questionsArray` for all objects/questions to `@"No"`.

My ScoreView has a button to Reset, but I don't know what to put in it to change **all** `questionCompleteOrNot` properties of the `questionsArray` to `@"No"`.

Sorry for the long question, I was trying to be very specific.

## Edit

Here is my DetailView for a tableView.

```
if ([[selectedQuestion questionCompleteOrNot] isEqualToString:@"No"])
    {
        if ([[selectedQuestion questionAnswer] caseInsensitiveCompare:answerField.text] == NSOrderedSame)
        {
            // Show the  correct label
            [correctLabel setHidden:NO];
            correctLabel.text = @"Correct!";
            correctLabel.textColor = [UIColor greenColor];

        }
        else
        {
            // Show the incorrect label
            [correctLabel setHidden:NO];
            correctLabel.text = @"Incorrect";
            correctLabel.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
            [incorrectPlayer play];
            [[selectedQuestion questionCompleteOrNot] isEqualToString:@"Yes"];
            
        }
        
        // Erase the text in the answerField
        answerField.text = @"";
    }
    if ([[selectedQuestion questionCompleteOrNot] isEqualToString:@"Yes"])
    {
        UIAlertView *error = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                              initWithTitle:@"Error"
                              message:@"You already answered this question. Please click the reset button on the score view to restart."
                              delegate:self
                              cancelButtonTitle:@"Okay!"
                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
        
        [error show];
        answerField.text = @"";
    }
    
    selectedQuestion.questionCompleteOrNot = @"Yes";
    correctLabel.text = @"";
    NSLog(@"Selected question's questionCompleteOrNot is %@", [selectedQuestion questionCompleteOrNot]);
```

Answer (score 10):

You can use `NSArray`'s [`makeObjectsPerformSelector:withObject:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/makeObjectsPerformSelector:withObject:), like so:

```
[questionsArray makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(setQuestionCompleteOrNot:) withObject:@"No"];
```

Comment: I did this in my ScoreView, QuestionList *ql = [[QuestionList alloc] init];
    [ql.questionsArray makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(setQuestionCompleteOrNot:) withObject:@"No"];, but it still does not work

Comment: Define "does not work". What happens? What are you trying to do? How is your QuestionList class connected to your ScoreView class? I need more information to determine what's wrong. My answer should work for any NSMutableArray, so it sounds to me like your problem is a wholly different question.

Comment: I have a completely different view, scoreView. My other view, questionList, has a NSMutableArray. I had to locally get QuestionList to acsess the array. I want to set **all** the questionCompleteOrNot properties on all objects to be No. It doesn't seem to be doing that because when my other view, which I forgot to post code about, which I will in a second, acsesses that property to see if it is no and does something. Here, I'll post it in the question. **Edit: Just updated it.**